# Using HeadlessUI Menu with Vue-Router

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, tailwind-css, headless-ui

I am trying to use a HealdessUI menu component together with vue-router. I could find a way to make this work. It seems, that HeadlessUI only works with Links as a sting. But I need to use something like this `this.$router.push({ name: item.href, hash: item.hash }`.

My routes are named but I need to give it a hash, so it actually scrolls to the anchor-ID on the site.

Answer (score 0):

`router.push(...)` is for programmatic navigation but there is also `<router-link>` for [declarative navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#router-link) that you can put in your component's template code:

```html
<MenuItem v-slot="{ active }">
  <router-link to="{ path: '/', hash: '#about' }">About</router-link>
</MenuItem>
```

Anchor links can be enabled by setting up [scrollBehavior](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html) in your router file:

```js
const router = createRouter({
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (to.hash) {
      return {
        el: to.hash,
        behavior: 'smooth',
      }
    }
  }
})
```